# How to find element by text using XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have HTML document downloaded and I need to find element in the tree by its text

snippet, only relevant part...

```
                                    <div class="py-5 col-12">
                                        <h4>Scale</h4>
                                        <div>
                                            <table class="table table-borderless">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th style="width: 300px;">Normalized Volume Percentile</th>
                                                        <td>
                                                            86<span style="position: relative; bottom: 1ex; font-size: 80%;">th</span>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Combined Orderbook Percentile</th>
                                                        <td>
                                                            82<span style="position: relative; bottom: 1ex; font-size: 80%;">th</span>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

I need to find **th** element *Normalized Volume Percentile* and then extract its **td** value 86

Search string I use `//Normalized Volume Percentile`

I was trying the following code and and it does not work

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc = web.Load(requesturl);

    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants();
    var body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//Normalized Volume Percentile");
```

Exception

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: ''//Normalized Volume Percentile' has an invalid token.'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to locate node by its text content try

```
"//th[.='Normalized Volume Percentile']"
```

To locate `td`:

```
"//th[.='Normalized Volume Percentile']/following-sibling::td"
```